# How to have a "cache per package.json" file in GitLab CI?

Tags: caching, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Vue web application that is built, tested and deployed using GitLab CI.

GitLab CI has a "[Cache](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cache)" feature where specific products of a Job can be cached so that future runs of the Job in the same Pipeline can be avoided and the cached products be used instead.

I'd like to improve my workflow's performance by caching the `node_modules` directory so it can be shared across Pipelines.

[GitLab Docs suggests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#caching-nodejs-dependencies) using `${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}` as the cache key to achieve this. However, this means "caching per-branch" and I would like to improve on that.

I would like to have a cache "per package.json". That is, only if there is a change in the contents of `package.json` will the cache key change and `npm install` will be run.

I was thinking of using a hash of the contents of the `package.json` file as the cache key. Is this possible with GitLab CI? If so, how?

Comment: A very good question. Having the same dream going on!

Comment: Seems that it's impossible right now but corresponding [feature request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/35862) already exists.

Answer (score 16):

This is now possible as of Gilab Runner v12.5

```
cache:
  key:
    files:
      - Gemfile.lock
      - package-lock.json // or yarn.lock
  paths:
    - vendor/ruby
    - node_modules
```

It means cache `key` will be a SHA checksum computed from the most recent commits (up to two, if two files are listed) that changed the given files. Whenever one of these files changes, a new cache key is computed and a new cache is created. Any future job runs using the same `Gemfile.lock` and `package.json` with `cache:key:files` will use the new cache, instead of rebuilding the dependencies.

More info: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cachekeyfiles

Also make sure to use always `--frozen-lockfile` flag in your CI jobs. (or `npm ci`) Regular `npm install` or `yarn install / yarn` commands generate new lock files and you wouldn't usually notice it until you install packages again. Thus makes your build artifacts and caches inconsistent.

Comment: You can also add prefix for this cache https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cachekeyprefix to got something like `my-test-cache-123456-files-hash`

Comment: Is there a reason you went for `package.json` over `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`?

Comment: Hi @justinvdk . Good question, using lock file is better for caching in CI with use of `--frozen-lockfile` flag. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to use wildcards under `files` keyword? I'm thinking (for dotnet) something like modules/*/*.csproj?

Comment: I believe you can use wildcard there. But there was a maximum file limit. I don't use Gitlab actively anymore. But I think you can find the necessary documentation on their docs website. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

For that behavior use `only:changes` parameter with a static cache name.

Ex:

```
install:
  image: node:latest
  script:
    - npm install
  cache:
    untracked: true 
    key: npm  #static name, can use any branch, any commit, etc..
    paths:
      - node_modules
  only:  #Only execute this job when theres a change in package.json
    changes:
      - package.json
```

If you need read this to set cache properly in runners:
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/autoscale.html#distributed-runners-caching https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/